# How to write djb2 hashing function in C?

Tags: c, dictionary, hash, hashtable

I am not able to figure out how to write the djb3 hashing function on C.

I searched the internet but I found it may be in C++...

```
unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str){
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        int c;

        while (c = *str++)
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

        return hash;
    }
```

and if you can explain this to me I will be really thankful...

Comment: Did you try this? This is valid (with warning) as C, but invalid as C++ because return type is missing.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh, I am really sorry I just missed the return type earlier. But I just fixed it.

Comment: What exactly do you need explained?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I just want to implement this in my c program. So I need this code in C to I can use it. And I have no idea what this code is doing, what do these mean... c = *str++ and what is hash << 5, specifically what does << mean?

Comment: `<<` means shift left (in this context). `hash << 5` is the same as `hash * 32` only more efficient. Most compilers will do that optimization automatically but not necessarily for `hash * 33` as is called for here.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you for your kind answer! Just one more question... what is happening in the while loop, the condition (c = *str++) an in c we cannot do this... it is showing an error.

Comment: `(c = *str++)` assigns the value pointed to by `str` to `c`, then increments `str`, then returns the value of `c` as the expression result. So as long as `c` is not null, the loop continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for djb2 Hashing function in C programming language!

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *word++))        // *str++ is going to the next address in memory, where the next char in the string is stored
    {
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            c = c + 32;
        }

        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; // hash * 33 + c   // hash << 5 = hash * 2^5
    }

    return hash % N;
}
```

Thanks to @500-InternalServerError for solving my doubts.